# Use preg_match_all across line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to get the the occurrences of a specific section from a website, and I've successfully done this before, but the difference now is that the sections spans across line breaks... As I've understood it, I should be able to do this with some modifiers...

So the structure of the section on the site in question is something like this:

```
<div id="LICRabatGuideAftale">
    <something in between>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="LICRabatGuideAftale">
    <something in between>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="LICRabatGuideAftale">
    <something in between>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

So I'm trying to get all occurrences with LICRabatGuideAftale and clear...

I've tried with:

```
preg_match_all ("/LICRabatGuideAftale(.*)clear/s", $link_section, $link_array);
```

but it doesn't seem to split the site into the sections, but just gives me 1 entry in the array...

Comment: What about triming all new lines before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*`.  The `?` makes the quantifier reluctant as opposed to greedy, so the match will stop at the *first* `clear` instead of the last.

Using the `U` modifier as suggested in the other answer is also a possibility.  This essentially inverts the behaviors of `.*` and `.*?` making them reluctant and greedy, respectively.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thanks! Will accept it as the answer when SO allows me to in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Make it ungreedy with U option:

```
preg_match_all ("`YOUR_REGEX`U", …);
```

Most often, I use:

```
preg_match_all ("`YOUR_REGEX`Uis", …);
```

Which makes it ungreedy, case insensitive.

Here are all the [**patterns modifiers**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) on php.net, in case you're interested.

Quote from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)** 
>  This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so that they are not greedy by default, but become
>   greedy if followed by ?. It is not compatible with Perl. It can also
>   be set by a (?U) modifier setting within the pattern or by a question
>   mark behind a quantifier (e.g. .*?).

Comment: Great tip for case insensitive... Really helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was definitely with the .* versus .*?
.* is greedy by default.

Here you go:

```
preg_match_all ("/LICRabatGuideAftale(.*?)clear/s", $link_section, $link_array);

foreach($link_array[1] as $match) {
    // Clean up scraps
    $data = preg_replace('/">\n\s*|\n\s*<div class="/', "", $match);
    echo $data;
}
```

Output:

```
 - <something in between>
 - <something in between>
 - <something in between>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the error :) Thanks for the extra little tip in the foreach with clean-up...

Comment: No problem.  It's actually a great example and way to learn greedy vs.  lazy. +1 to your question.